# npm test error for create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm getting this error when I run `npm run test` for a create-react-app application for the sample test provided. I tried looking for the EMFILE error but I'm unable to understand what's going wrong.

`Error: Error watching file for changes: EMFILE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1406:11)`

Comment: EMFILE error means that your program is trying to open too many files. You can raise the number of files it can open by runnning `ulimit -n 2048` in your terminal (on linux and mac)

Comment: Alright. I tried doing that. However, the error still persists.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and discovered `watchman` was not installed.
Run `brew install watchman`.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is happening since `watchman` is not installed on your system.

On Linux, you need to do following

1. Install `Watchman` using following commands

   - git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
   - cd watchman/
   - git checkout v4.9.0
   - sudo apt-get install -y autoconf automake build-essential python-dev libssl-dev libtool
   - ./autogen.sh
   - ./configure
   - make
   - sudo make install
2. Execute tests

   - sudo npm test