# React - npm start fails with error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

NPM start throwing the following error

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Error watching file for changes: EMFILE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1406:11)
```

I have tried

```
rm -rf node-modules/

npm install

npm run build
```

but the error still occurs.

Comment: there might be something else running on port 4040 or whatever you are using
try closing all npm related programs and then running it again

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a similar issue with the same solution as that for which I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203073/npm-test-error-for-create-react-app)
You have to install `watchman` with `brew install watchman`.